# If input date is not within a range on another sheet in excel then show warning message VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am creating a table to allow a user to add employees to a project and I wish to protect it from user error as best I can.

The table looks like the following

[image: Allocation]

The user adds an employee to a project and then enters the dates they wish them to be on it. I'd like to catch if the date entered in to the Start Date is within the project start date and end date (On the Project Info sheet) and show a warning message if not. I'd also like to have an additional check to determine if the start date is within the employee start date (on the Staff Details sheet) and employee end date (this could be blank) and show a different message if it isn't.

Project Info Sheet Layout :

[image: Project Info]

Staff Details Sheet Layout :

[image: Staff Details]

Is it possible to trigger a warning message straight after the user has input some data into a specifc column cell and if so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your *Project Info* sheet is a table I've named *ProjectTable* and your main table is on *Sheet1*.

With cell `F2` selected create this `Name` I've called `ProjectStartDate` - *(Formulas > Name Manager)*
`=XLOOKUP(Sheet1!$B2,ProjectTable[Project Name],ProjectTable[Start Date])`
This will return the Start Date for the specified project.
`Sheet1!$B2` should reference the Project Name.

In `Data Validation` add this Custom validation:
`=$F2>=ProjectStartDate`

Now do the same for the end date -
`=XLOOKUP(Sheet1!$B2,ProjectTable[Project Name],ProjectTable[End Date])` and
`$G2<=ProjectEndDate`

Comment: Hi Darren, 
The sheet the employee data is on a different sheet. The employee table is AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl and project table is ProjectInfoTbl. I first selected F2, opened the name manager, clicked new, named it ProjectStartDate and then added the following for the formula - =XLOOKUP(ProjectInfoTbl[@[Start Date]],ProjectInfoTbl[Project Name],ProjectInfoTbl[Start Date]). I select F2, Data Validation, custom and input =$F2>=ProjectStartDate. It says formula evaluates to an error. Changing ProjectStartDate to a number to test fixed it. It's like it can't see ProjectStartDate, any idea?

Comment: it also feels like something is wrong with what I have as it doesn't compare the Project Name in the ProjectInfoTbl with the Project Name in the AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl to get the correct start date to then compare with the emplyee start date on the project

Comment: `=XLOOKUP(ProjectInfoTbl[@[Start Date]],` is looking at the Start Date, have it look at the Project Name as a cell reference `$E2` keeping the row number relative.  I had the same problem when trying to reference a column table.

Comment: Have updated answer to show what `Sheet1!$B2` should be looking at.

Comment: Thanks Darren. That works and gives me the following message - The value doesn't match the data validation restrictions defined for this cell. This obviously makes sense to me but when I give the sheet to someone else to use it probably won't. Is there a way to customise the message to say what is actually happening - the input employee project start date is before the project start date, please input a date in the range 01/01/2020 - 31/03/2023 for example?

Comment: figured out the custom message. I can't have it grab the start and end dates of the project but I can work with it.

Comment: Hi Darren, Do you know how I incorporate the employee start date in to this logic too please? So if the project start date entered is before the employee start date in the StaffDetailsTbl I can show a similar error or the same and combine it with the current one.

Comment: I have created StaffStartDate in the NameManager =XLOOKUP('Staff Project Allocation'!$A2,StaffDetailsTbl[Employee],StaffDetailsTbl[Employment Start Date]) and adjusted the data validation to =AND($F2>=ProjectStartDate,$F2>=StaffStartDate) and this works. It'd be great if I could show a different message if the date is before the project start date as opposed to the date being before the employee start date. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  I can't think of any non-VBA route to put more than one type of validation on a cell.